# Import and export schema in cassandra

Tags: database, cassandra, schema, database-schema, cqlsh

How to import and export schema from Cassandra or Cassandra cqlsh prompt?

Answer (score 69):

To export keyspace schema:

```
cqlsh -e "DESC KEYSPACE user" > user_schema.cql
```

To export entire database schema:

```
cqlsh -e "DESC SCHEMA" > db_schema.cql
```

To import schema open terminal at 'user_schema.cql' ('db_schema.cql') location (or you can specify the full path) and open cqlsh shell. Then use the following command to import keyspace schema:

```
source 'user_schema.cql'
```

To import full database schema:

```
source 'db_schema.cql'
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfect!  (I had to include IP/hostname after cqlsh because our instance uses an rpc_address in the config).

Comment: I am trying to export my schema called crmdata with its data, can you please tell me where do i need to run this cmd `cqlsh -e "crmdata" > db_schema.cql`

Answer (score 14):

Everything straight from the command line. No need to go into cqlsh.

Import schema (.cql file):

```
$ cqlsh -e "SOURCE '/path/to/schema.cql'"
```

Export keyspace:

```
$ cqlsh -e "DESCRIBE KEYSPACE somekeyspace" > /path/to/somekeyspace.cql
```

Export database schema:

```
$ cqlsh -e "DESCRIBE SCHEMA" > /path/to/schema.cql
```

Answer (score 12):

If using cassandra-cli, you can use the 'show schema;' command to dump the whole schema.  You can restrict to a specific keyspace by running 'use *keyspace*;' first.

You can store the output in a file, then import with 'cassandra-cli -f *filename*'.

If using cqlsh, you can use the 'describe schema' command.  You can restrict to a keyspace with 'describe keyspace *keyspace*'.

You can save this to a file then import with 'cqlsh -f *filename*'.

Comment: Hi Richard,

Thank for your reply. You have specified import the keyspace in both service. But, I need to both service in how to import and export keyspace on cassandra-cli and cqlsh?.                                          
Please provide the information with syntax.

Comment: @vpggopal I think you might have to pay him for that.

Comment: If you used cassandra-cli to create your schema then use the cassandra-cli commands I wrote above.  If you used cqlsh then use the cqlsh commands.  Don't use both and note that cassandra-cli won't include cql3 tables in its output.

Comment: Thank u Richard, How to export schema in cqlsh using command?.

Comment: It's written in my answer. Use 'describe schema'.

Comment: Richard, its working fine, but where it is stored the exported schema we have used the "describe schema" command and which format it will be stored?.

Comment: It's the text output. Put it in a file and import with the 'cqlsh -f' command.

Comment: Thank you Richard, If possible to write the 'describe keyspace' command output text on any file format?.

Comment: Richard, how to use aggregate function in cassandra 1.2.3 OR which version is support to aggregate function?

Comment: @vpggopal : you can easily get the schema in a file using `echo -e "describe keyspace <keyspace>;\n" | cqlsh > <keyspace>.shema`

Answer (score 12):

For someone who comes in future, just to get ddl for schema/keyspace with "myschema" in "CassandraHost" server.

```
echo -e "use myschema;\nDESCRIBE KEYSPACE;\n" | cqlsh  CassandraHost > mySchema.cdl
```

and you can use following to import just DDL (without data):

```
cqlsh  CassandraNEWhost -f mySchema.cdl
```

Comment: This only works with a remote host if they're on a compatible version.

Answer (score 0):

## With authentication

```
cqlsh -u <user-name> -e "DESC KEYSPACE user" > user_schema.cql
```

password will be promted.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working with cassandra 1.1 and moving towards 1.2

For older Cassandra versions (<2.0), I found the below to be a handy way:

```
$ cqlsh -f testFile > user_schema_export.cql
```

**Usage:**

```
cqlsh [options] [host [port]]
```

```
CQL Shell for Apache Cassandra

Options:

  -f FILE, --file=FILE  Execute commands from FILE, then exit
```

The testFile can contain the DESC command as needed for our keyspace.

```
 $ vagrant@vagrant-cass-VM:/cassandra/bin$ cat testFile 
   use testkeyspace;
   DESC KEYSPACE testkeyspace;
```