# Generating CREATE TABLE statements for Cassandra keyspace

Tags: cassandra, admin

In Cassandra, is there a way to generate `CREATE TABLE` statements for all the existing tables inside a particular keyspace?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import and export schema in cassandra](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16440606/import-and-export-schema-in-cassandra)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DESC KEYSPACE KEYSPACE_NAME**

> Output CQL commands for the given keyspace. These CQL commands can be used to recreate the keyspace and tables.