# cassandra restore from incremental backup

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I want to use incremental backup as main cassandra backup type in my system, but I have some miss understanding:

1. The one way to make restore from incremental backup that worked for me - just copy from backup folder to table folder , is that the right way to make it?
2. Can I ,somehow , make backup of table\keyspace parameters , like index/replica_factor etc?

Thanks.

Comment: Regarding backup schema , I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49008626/cassandra-backup-including-schema)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you have not dropped the table.for restoration

   Stop the C* node

   Copy the backup folder to table directory. You are right on that.

   Start the server.
2. If you want schema, you can check snapshot folder. There you can find schema.cql

Comment: +1 from me.  You can also run `nodetool refresh` (after the copy) to get a hot node to pick up the backup files.